# Can I get rid of persistence.xml when using Hibernate with Spring?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jpa

I'm always looking for ways to eliminate redundant code from my project.

I am using Hibernate with Spring.  I have configured Spring's JPA LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean, which lets me pass a bunch of properties to the JPA provider (Hibernate), which means I don't need to set those properties in the persistence.xml file.

Furthermore, Hibernate can find my persistent classes without my having to actually identify them in persistence.xml, so those <class> lines go away too.

I'm left with one line in my persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="bigDatabase" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL"/>
```

Does anyone know a way to eliminate persistence.xml completely and move the persistence unit definition into the Spring configuration file?  I tried Googling of course but couldn't find an answer.

Thanks!

Comment: You could consider replacing the JPA `EntityManager` with Hibernate's native `SessionFactory`.... less config that way

Comment: @skaffman @duffymo ts ts ts, replacing an open standard

Comment: @S.P.Floyd: Yeah, but it's a sub-standard standard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`persistence.xml` is not mandatory for JPA configurations. You can create your entity manager with the [EntityManagerFactory.createEntityManager(map)](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory.html#createEntityManager%28java.util.Map%29)
 method. But [`LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.html) doesn't have methods that helps creation of entity manager with a map. So you have to extend `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` and override some methods according to your needs.

Comment: good answer, bad link. inserted correct api docs link for you

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736301/is-persistence-xml-requied-when-working-with-spring-hibernate