# OpenJPA creating EntityManager in code without persistence.xml, with properties

Tags: java, persistence, openjpa, entitymanager

I need to create EntityManager in code without persistence.xml ...
I have

```
props.put("openjpa.ConnectionURL", "jdbc:sqlserver://databasehost:3306; DatabaseName=dbname; selectMethod=cursor;create=true");
    props.put("openjpa.ConnectionDriverName","com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    props.put("openjpa.ConnectionUserName", "dbname");
    props.put("openjpa.ConnectionPassword", "password");
    props.put("openjpa.jdbc.SynchronizeMappings", "buildSchema");
    props.put("openjpa.Log", "DefaultLevel=WARN, Runtime=INFO, Tool=INFO, SQL=TRACE");
    props.put("openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses", "supported");

    EntityManagerFactory factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("wp");
    em = factory.createEntityManager(props);
```

..and when em = factory.createEntityManager(props) is called I get :

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No persistence providers available for "wp" after trying the following discovered implementations: org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:182)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:72)
    at dao.wp.WP_EMH.getCurrentEntityManager(WP_EMH.java:27)
```

I understand that there is no mention about something that is in persistence.xml represented by tag

PROVIDER- org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl - /PROVIDER

How should I add this to Properties? Or how to solve it?
And my second question is that in persistence.xml are added classes of entities. How to solve this with properties?

thanks

Comment: Please don't set openjpa.RuntimeUnenhancedClasses=supported ... that will bite you sometime down the road. The better bet is to configure build time enhancement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method

```
javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(
    String persistenceUnitName);
```

expects configuration from `persistence.xml`. Try supplying your property map to

```
javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(
    String persistenceUnitName, Map properties);
```

Clearly, though, the property set is incomplete; it lacks, for example, persistent class names:

```
properties.put("openjpa.MetaDataFactory", "jpa(Types=FQN.class1;FQN.class2;...)");
```

Comment: Did you confirm that supplying the property map to createEntityManagerFactory does indeed work, or is this an assumption?

Comment: It's how we configure EMF in my current assignment, indirectly by Spring. We do use persistence.xml, though. I'm counting on feedback from falconseye.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing what you come up with. I am nearly certain that having a persistence.xml file is required.

Comment: @Rick It is required by specification, but you can circumvent this, by mimicking what Spring LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean does. It is not easy to do; see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736301/is-persistence-xml-requied-when-working-with-spring-hibernate/4736615#4736615 ; I'm all the more curious of results.

Comment: when I wrote this question I had already some persistence.xml ...but with different settings, other database, other tables, different PU name. I have removed it and did what Mada wrote...And now it work fit, bit slower probably because of runtime enhancement. Then I put persistence.xml to META-INF again and added new persistence-unit tag with name of WP - those PU which was created with properties. And it works as well ..

Comment: The answer isn't complete. How do you add the provider?