# Specify Hibernate-Search runtime directory

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jndi, hibernate-search

I'm new to Hibernate-Search. In the getting started guide, it said that I can specify where to store the index using these two property.

```
<property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider"
          value="filesystem"/>

<property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase"
          value="/var/lucene/indexes"/>
```

The problem is, that is a static path which may not be the same in development and production. How to change the path at runtime? Through JNDI maybe, or some way to modify persistence.xml at runtime.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use build time filtering. You would filter the right value (depending on the targeted environment) into *persistence.xml*. I've used this approach before and it works quite nicely.

An alternative would be to use a relative path. The directory gets then created relative to the directory in which the jvm gets started.

Last but not least, if you are using Spring you could have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9264931/set-dynamic-index-directory-for-hibernate-search-in-spring) as well.